# Angular 6 Importing JQVMap - Property 'vectorMap' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: jquery, angular, angular6, jqvmap, external-js

I am trying to import a clickable map, [JQVMap](https://www.10bestdesign.com/jqvmap/) and therefore JQuery into my Angular 6 project and I am having some teething problems.

Exception: **error TS2339: Property 'vectorMap' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.**

**My component:**

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

@Component({
selector: 'app-example',
templateUrl: './explore.component.html'
})

export class ExampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {

ngAfterViewInit() {
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
  {
    map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
    borderColor: '#818181',
    borderOpacity: 0.25,
    borderWidth: 1,
    color: '#f4f3f0',
    enableZoom: true,
    hoverColor: '#c9dfaf',
    hoverOpacity: null,
    normalizeFunction: 'linear',
    scaleColors: ['#b6d6ff', '#005ace'],
    selectedColor: '#c9dfaf',
    selectedRegions: null,
    showTooltip: true
    });
   }

  }
```

I have installed JQuery through npm and the necessary JVQMap scripts within the assets directory. JQuery seems to be working correctly.

**angular.json**

```
 "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
          "./src/assets/js/jquery.vmap.js",
          "./src/assets/js/jquery.vmap.world.js"]
      },
```

Apologies if this a trivial or stupid error. I am new to Angular and JS in general

Comment: You would not have to include jquery itself there as that's picked up with your import. Maybe that's causing a duplicate jquery instance.

Also, you're sure the path to jquery.vmap.js is correct?

Comment: I have removed the reference to jquery,  but still have the exception. I have checked the jquery.vmap.js is valid.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare const jQuery: any;
```